# Quarto: show and evaluate markdown chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, quarto

Is it possible to show and evaluate a markdown text in Quarto / Rmarkdown?

I need to show both the raw markdown script and its compiled (evaluated) form, one after another. In Quarto, I can use the following code to show/format a markdown code, but this does not provide evaluated results (i.e. the link).

````
```{markdown}
#| echo: true
#| eval: true
[Quarto](https://quarto.org)
```
````

Thanks

Comment: I received the following [reply](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3303) at Quarto github page. It is not possible to implement this as markdown is not a knitr language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own evaluator with a Quarto Lua filter:

```lua
function CodeBlock (cb)
  if cb.classes:includes 'markdown' and cb.classes:includes 'eval' then
    return {cb} .. pandoc.read(cb.text).blocks
  end
end
```

Save the code to a file in your project and add that file to the `filters` YAML entry:

```yaml
---
filters:
  - markdown-examples.lua
---
```

The filter requires slightly different syntax though:

````markdown
```{.markdown .eval}
[Quarto](https://quarto.org)
```
````

This isn't fully satisfying though, as it only supports pandoc's Markdown and doesn't know about Quarto extensions to it.

Comment: This works as expected! great.... Thanks @tarleb..

Comment: Is it possible to exclude comments after the hashtag from the output? For example
```{.markdown .eval}
[Quarto](https://quarto.org) # a comment
```

Comment: You  could replace `cb.text` with `cb.text:gsub(' +# .*\n', '')` to get rid of comments.

Comment: Thanks @tarleb... It did not work. It gives this error when render the file `Error running filter ../Quarto_markdown.lua:
PandocLuaError "Unknown reader: 0"
stack traceback:
 ../Quarto_markdown.lua:3: in function 'CodeBlock'`

Comment: That's a Lua pitfall that I always forget about. Please try to wrap the replacement code into an extra pair of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks... Now there is no error. I needed to make a slight change in the regex to make it works (at least in one example); by replacing the match pattern with `" +# .+"`